# SharePoint SPFx Web Part Accessibility Tab Issue

Tags: spfx-webparts

Has anyone had issues with accessibility of components inside of a SPFx web part, specifically when you tab through the UI elements it skips the web part even though it has buttons and anchor links. The components I'm having issue with are web components leveraging Coveo Atomic UI: https://docs.coveo.com/en/atomic/latest/usage/frameworks/atomic-react-wrapper/

Any thoughts or ideas on how to solve? The Coveo Atomic UI itself is tab accessible, but when put inside SharePoint doesn't support tab keyboard navigation. I don't believe it is a tab index issue, feels like something more internal colliding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Microsoft Accessibility library doesn't like Web Components that specifically use a Shadow Dom. We have been able to reproduce the issue and are working on a support ticket to see if it can be supported. Reference stand-alone reproduction: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9005

Thanks to my amazing colleague Tom White on the investigation.